# How to integrate existing mongodb database to current project?

Tags: mongodb, express

I am trying to create a workout app api using express, and mongodb. I plan on creating a list of exercises so the users can see all of them on the app, but the exercises can also be part of a workout created by the user. Users could also add their own exercises, but these will not be added to the default list of exercises created by me. My question is. If an user is creating a workout, how do I add an exercise from the exercises list database to their own custom workout. I am sorry if this does not make sense, please ask me any questions and I could clarify more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a high level, I would suggest that you create a database for all standard workouts that you have. Besides that you will create a database for each user in which you can add the custom workouts that he/she choose. Databases will have the exercises as records.